# Android Listview - Custom Adapter not displaying anything

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I am stuck with a problem (stupid one, probably), where I couldn't figure out what is wrong with my ListView.  I have a custom adapter, and I am able to pass data to it, but it is not displaying anything.  Here is my code:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.nutrition_main, null);
        listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.listviewtextview);

        for (ParseObject calories : ob) {
            Log.i("Calories", calories.get("Calories").toString());
            adapter.add(calories.get("Calories") + "");
        }

        ArrayList<String> kapow = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
            String str = (String)adapter.getItem(i);
            kapow.add(str);
            Log.i("str", str);
        }
        SomeAdapter eh = new SomeAdapter(getActivity(), kapow);
        listview.setAdapter(eh);
        eh.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is my SomeAdapter class code:

```
public class SomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> mItem;

public SomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> itemsArrayList) {
    super(context, R.layout.listviewtextview, itemsArrayList);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mItem = itemsArrayList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewtextview, parent, false);
    TextView mFoodName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.food_name);v.findViewById(R.id.food_description);
    mFoodName.setText(mItem.get(position) + "");
    return v;
}
}
```

And last but not least, here is my listviewtextview.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/row_activated"
android:layout_height="88dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/food_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/food_brand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/food_name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/food_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you use `listview.setAdapter(eh);` and 
       `eh.notifyDataSetChanged();` together?

Comment: Is your layout being correctly inflated in the activity?

Comment: getting `Log.i("str", str);` line executed ?

Comment: Make sure `ob` contains data and also you have added inflated view as child of your visible view

Comment: inside adapter...use inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewtextview,null)

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni Yes, ob contains data.  The getting/extracting data is working fine, but putting that data into the ListView isn't.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yes, that line is being executed fine.  Just putting it into the ListView is the problem.

Comment: @DavidFang Yes, the layout is being properly inflated.  In nutrition_main, there is only one element, which is the listview, and I'm calling that.

Comment: @Rohodude: no sure just try to override `getCount()` method in Adapter and return `itemsArrayList.size()`

Comment: which class code is the one you mentioned on top from where you are initializing and calling SomeAdapter from?

Comment: @Rohodude post your whole class someAdapter

Comment: @Aashvi That is my entire class.

Comment: post your fragment class and fragment xml file

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have some kind of misconception about custom list views and their adapters, Since you are setting your listview's adapter as `eh` you don't even need to have that array adapter, you have not only created the array adapter but pushed data into it, then you get the data from the array adapter one by one and put it into kapow? All you need to do is initialize your adapter `eh` with data and `listview.setadapter(eh)`

```
 View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.nutrition_main, null);
    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // YOU DONT NEED THIS ADAPTER !
    // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
    // ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
    //        R.layout.listviewtextview);

    // just pass your calories string to the kapow list.                
    ArrayList<String> kapow = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ParseObject calories : ob) {
        Log.i("Calories", calories.get("Calories").toString());
        kapow.add(calories.get("Calories") + "");
    }

    // You dont need this either
    /*for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
        String str = (String)adapter.getItem(i);
        kapow.add(str);
        Log.i("str", str);
    }*/

    SomeAdapter eh = new SomeAdapter(getActivity(), kapow);
    listview.setAdapter(eh);
    eh.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**EDIT**

Your adapter with viewholder

```
public class SomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mItem;

    public SomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> itemsArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.listviewtextview, itemsArrayList);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mItem = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewtextview, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.food_name);v.findViewById(R.id.food_description);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convert.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.textView.setText(mItem.get(position) + "");
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm still not getting anything in the ListView.  Do you see anything else wrong?

Comment: tell me where have you put the above code in your activity? also follow the viewholder pattern in your adapter

Comment: I put the above code in place of where my previous code was (I commented the previous code out).

Comment: Ok yeah, I am totally doing something wrong that I can't figure out.  Even that isn't working in my code.  I know that I am getting all of the values correctly from 'calories.get("Calories").toString()' because I am able to see all of the values getting spit out by LogCat.  I'm still not sure why the ListView isn't working though.

Comment: @Rohodude btw I dont see any listview in your xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AFrag extends Fragment{
    private View view = null;
    public static final String TAG = "A";
    ListView listview;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.afrag, container, false);
            listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            //Create your arraylist here no need to get it from adapter
            // For testing & sample here i took characters loop.
            ArrayList<String> kapow = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (char y = 'a'; y <= 'z'; y++) {
                kapow.add(String.valueOf(y));
            }
//            for (ParseObject calories : ob) {
//                Log.i("Calories", calories.get("Calories").toString());
//                ///Fill arraylist direct from the parseobject.
//                //no need to add to adapter & from adapter to arraylist
//                kapow.add(calories.get("Calories") + "");
//            }

            SomeAdapter eh = new SomeAdapter(getActivity(), kapow);
            listview.setAdapter(eh);
//            no need to call notifyDataSetChanged if you your data not changed after setting adapter
//            eh.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return view;
    }

    public class SomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<String> mItem;

        public SomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> itemsArrayList) {
            super(context, R.layout.listviewtextview, itemsArrayList);
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mItem = itemsArrayList;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            public TextView txtFoodName;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder v = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listviewtextview, parent, false);
                v = new ViewHolder();
                v.txtFoodName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_name);
                convertView.setTag(v);
            } else {
                v = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            v.txtFoodName.setText(mItem.get(position) + "");
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**ListView Item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="88dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_brand"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/food_name"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/label"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment main layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtCurrent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onBtnClick"
        android:text="Go to B" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you are using Fragment than above i have posted code and also given comment for the same

Suggestion please check [ViewHolder](http://goo.gl/0lKSfl) pattern for listview

And you can also check below answers for Listview related 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28105884/1140237

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28104066/1140237

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't do it either.  Do you see anything else wrong?  And yes, I am using a fragment.

Comment: can you please post your entire code ? as this things must work.. might be something wrong with other things... just confirming activity declartion in manifest & fragment replacing things are done properly or no ...